# What does resolve and reject actually do in Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

At first, I think `resolve` simply pass the parameter to the function in `then`, so I tried this

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(new Promise(resolve => resolve(2333)))
})
// promise.then(innerPromise => {
//   innerPromise.then(num => console.log(num))
// })
promise.then(num => console.log(num))
```

The lines commented got an error:`innerPromise.then is not a function`, so I assume `resolve` will firstly help you handle the promise inside if you have a promise as the paramter

So I tried `reject`, I think it will be the same

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject(new Promise(resolve => resolve(2333)))
})
promise.then(null, innerPromise => {
  innerPromise.then(num => console.log(num))
})
// promise.then(null, num => console.log(num))
```

The lines uncommented will log `2333`, the lines commented will simply log the rejected `Promise` instance

Comment: Try not to use the same variable name twice inside a closure. Change the inner `resolve` to something else.

Comment: You are right. When you resolve to a `Promise`, the resolve callback will actually wait for that promise to resolve and send you the value. In short, you can say that you are never going to receive a `Promise` in a `.then` callback, but the final value of all the "promises chain". WHen you `reject`, you will simply get the `reject` argument because has no sense to reject to a `Promise`. You usually reject to an `Error`.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve is a callback used to return the value or the result of another promise.

So when you execute the below code in first block:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(new Promise(resolve => resolve(2333)))
})

promise.then(innerPromise => {
      console.log(innerPromise)
//    innerPromise.then(num => console.log(num))
})

promise.then(num => console.log(num))
```

You will find the inner functions are executed automatically by the Resolve, thus getting the final result of functions inside resolve. Secondly, it is clearly mentioned that **'Resolve' returns a** **'Value'** and not a callable object. So, you cannot call the result of a promise like a function.

In case of Reject, reject callback is used to reject the promise with a provided reason or error. You may return any statement (that represents error) or a callable object that returns you the error message from error code. (That's how I use the Reject to fetch the messages from Error codes generated)

Well, you can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

By the defination, resolve can take value and thenable value. If thenable value, it will resolve and return the state. However, reject only take as value. Even if value it promise(thenable). It wont resolve it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Argument to be resolved by this Promise. ***Can also be a Promise or a thenable to resolve***

The Promise.resolve() method returns a Promise object that is resolved with a given value. If the value is a promise, that promise is returned; if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value. This function flattens nested layers of promise-like objects (e.g. a promise that resolves to a promise that resolves to something) into a single layer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject

The Promise.reject() method returns a Promise object that is rejected with a given reason.

Comment: Just for memorizing, using `resolve` means you are doing sth good, so `resolve` can help you handle a little bit, while `reject` has no sense to help u, `reject` thinks whatever you reject as an error and directly rejects it